# Cannot return JSON object to calling program

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am running the code below that allows a user to log in to a system. As part of this functionality, a HTTP POST is being used (which returns an Observable). Since this is using JWT, I have to pull out the values that are in the TOKEN.

I would like to return an Observable (with these TOKEN values) to the calling program in JSON format. I have tried using the map functionality as follows:

```
adminLogin(username, password) {
        let url = `${this._apiRoot}/login`;
        let tokenResp = {};


        this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response' })
          .map(response => response.json())
          .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
         [ ... snip ...]
```

But my experience has been that the "subscribe" never gets called.

What can I do?

TIA

**original code**

```
adminLogin(username, password) {
        let url = `${this._apiRoot}/login`;
        let tokenResp = {};


        this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response' })

          .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {

            let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");

            if (token) {

              let t = JWT(token);

              console.log("-- what is in the token --");
              console.log(t);

              // need to set the value here
              this.userLoggedIn.next(setUser);

            }
          },
          (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (error.error instanceof Error) {
              let errorFound = console.error(error.status + " " 
                    + error.error.message + " " + error.message );
              console.error(errorFound);
              return Observable.throw(errorFound);
            }
            else {
              let errorFound = "Server-Side Error has taken place ";
              console.error(errorFound);
              return Observable.throw(new Error(errorFound));
            }
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return an observable with the Token (whatever type), you cannot have your subscribe method argument type as HttpResponse.I thought you'd get ts compilation error

Try that

```
adminLogin(username, password) : Observable<JWT> //Assuming this is a type
    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response' })

              .map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {

                let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");

                if (token) {

                  let t = JWT(token);

                  return t;
                }
                return null; //Or error
              },
          //Error handling
```

And in calling method

```
adminLogin(username,password).subscribe((token: JWT )=>
{
//use token
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. For the calling method, I get "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'". What happened here?